# Finding maximum and minimum value in a matrix column using Octave

Tags: matrix, octave

I have a 10 x 2 sample matrix as follows

```
2104      3
1600      3
2400      3
1416      2
3000      4
1985      4
1534      3
1427      3
1380      3
1494      3
```

I need a generalized method to find the minimum and maximum value in a column.

I can use 
    `max(max(X))` to find the maximum value in a matrix, but not of a column.

Also, `max(min(X))` to find the minimum value is not a generalized solution.

Comment: 'max(X)' finds the maximum in the columns, have you tried it?

Comment: Yep. It works. I hadn't thought of that. @CrisLuengo 's solution works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a matrix `X`, `max(X)` will return the maximum value in each column. You can index the result to get the value for a given column:

```
max(X)(1)  % max of the fist column (doesn't work in MATLAB)
```

Alternatively, extract the column and get its max:

```
max(X(:,1))  % max of the fist column
```

`max` (and many similar functions) operate on columns by default. To get the maximum of each row, use `max(X,[],2)`.